# Python Thread Loop method wont continue code

Tags: python, multithreading

I have two instances of the same class, with a Lock variable declared globally.

This classes have a .run() method that creates a Thread that will run another method from the same class ( these two methods are in the end of the question)

I have some test print statements as follows in my code as follows:

[main.py]

```
first = className()
second = className()
print('test before first')
first.run()
print('test before second')
second.run()
```

and my output is:

[output]

```
test before first
first Thread lock acquired by first
first Thread lock released (will sleep now)
first Thread lock acquired by first
first Thread lock released (will sleep now)
```

and it never gets to this line, where it should start another thread that would compete for the resource using mutex ' threading.Lock() ':

[main.py]

```
print('test before second')
```

Class methods running:

[className.py]

```
def run(self):
    tr = threading.Thread(target= self.update())
    tr.start()
    return True

def update(self):
    while(True):
        try:
            global lock
            lock.acquire()
            print('first Thread lock acquired by ' + self.name)
            #do stuff
            lock.release()
            print('lock release')
            sleep(2)
        except:
            sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second line of the run Method, the target value should be the method name without the parenthesis.

```
def run(self):
    tr = threading.Thread(target= self.update)
    # Instead of:  
    tr = threading.Thread(target= self.update())
    tr.start()
```

The difference is, in the original one, the tr variable will wait for the result from the method, and will never finish. 
In the correct one, tr will start running and the program will continue.

Comment: Are you answering your own question?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out while finishing the question. So I chose the option "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style "